# Problem accessing navigation parameters in consuming component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having difficulty of accessing parameters passed from component named **NewsPageScreen.js**. the parameters are passed to **BrowserScreen.js**. My app has Main Navigator component called **MainTabNavigator.js** that displays Bottom Tabs. The 'News' tab is connected to NewsPageScreen.js and this is where I am passing the the parameter to BrowserScreen.js but for some reason I am unable to access the parameters BrowserScreen.js, Can anyone help me see what I am getting wrong because it is giving me **undefined**. All my files are shown below:

MainTabNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs'

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'


import NewsPageScreen from '../screens/NewsPageScreen';
import FavouriteScreen from '../screens/FavouriteScreen';
import SettingScreen from '../screens/SettingScreen';
import BrowserScreen from '../screens/BrowserScreen';

const Colors = {
    tabIconDefault: '#ccc',
    tabIconSelected: '#2f95dc'
  }

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
     News: createStackNavigator({ 
      News: NewsPageScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'News'
      }),
    }),
    Favourite: createStackNavigator({
      Favourite: FavouriteScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Favourite'
      }),
    }),
    Setting: createStackNavigator({
      Setting: SettingScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Setting'
      }),
    }),
     Browser: createStackNavigator({
       Browser: BrowserScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: navigation.state.params.title
      }),
    }),
  }, {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      
      let IconComponent = Ionicons ;
      let iconName;
      switch (routeName) {
        case 'News':
          //iconName = `ios-information-circle`;
          iconName = focused ? 'ios-information-circle' : 'ios-information-circle-outline'
          break;
        case 'Favourite':
          iconName = `ios-link`;
          break;
        case 'Setting':
          iconName = `ios-options`;
      }
      return 
        <IconComponent 
          name={iconName}
          size={28} 
          style={{marginBottom: -3}}
          //color={tintColor}
          color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
        />
      
          },
      }),
      tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      animationEnabled: false,
      swipeEnabled: false,
    
  });


const MainTabNavigator = createAppContainer(tabNavigator)
export default MainTabNavigator;
```

NewsPageScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, View,StyleSheet,Text,SafeAreaView,} from 'react-native';
  
export default class NewsPageScreen extends Component {

    state = {
        links: [
          {
            title: 'Smashing Magazine',
            url: 'https://www.smashingmagazine.com/articles/'
          },
          {
            title: 'CSS Tricks',
            url: 'https://css-tricks.com/'
          },
          
         ],
      };

      handleButtonPress = (button) => {
        const { url, title } = button;
        this.props.navigation.navigate('BrowserScreen', { url, title });
        
      }

      renderButton = (button, index) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={() => this.handleButtonPress(button)}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>{button.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }

      
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
              <View>
              <Text style={styles.newsTitle}>Scan The Somali world News</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.buttonList}>
                {this.state.links.map(this.renderButton)}
              </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonList: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#c0392b',
    borderRadius: 3,
    padding: 10,
    paddingRight: 30,
    paddingLeft: 30,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  newsTitle: {
      color:'#000',
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginTop: 20
  }
});
```

BrowserScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class BrowserScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        
        
        //console.log(navigation)
        
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        console.log(params)

        return (      
            /**
             * use the webview here to display the webpage
             */ 
             <WebView source={{ uri: url }}  />  
        )
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import AppIntroSlider from "react-native-app-intro-slider";


import MainTabNavigatorp from './src/navigation/MainTabNavigator';

export default function App() {


  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    
        <MainTabNavigator /> 
        
     </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: { 
    flex: 1, 
    paddingTop: 20, 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    padding: 20 
   }, 
  slide: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  image: {
    width: 220,
    height: 220,
    marginVertical: 32,
  },
  description: {
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 25,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },

});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the navigation.getParam function?

Comment: Joao I have used the same code without bottom tab navigator, it worked perfectly. But there something that I am not getting right with the use of  bottomTab Navigator and StackNavigator.